# Why does Ios viewPager crashed with UISearchController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Now i have one issue during ios app development.
I made one viewpagercontrollerview include several viewcontroller.
Each Viewcontroller include tableview.
I used UISearchController in this tableview.
But, whenever i click searchcontroller and tab scrolled, then error is occured.

```
 2016-08-08 22:07:11.211 ToolManager[3913:121312] *** Assertion failure in -[_UIQueuingScrollView _setWrappedViewAtIndex:withView:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/_UIQueuingScrollView.m:332
2016-08-08 22:07:11.222 ToolManager[3913:121312] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unexpected subviews'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c3dd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001046b1deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c3dbea +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x00000001042fbd5a -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
```

But, Without click searchcontrol and scroll,then work is done well.
I saw several resolution...
one method is dismiss searchcontroller before scrool tab.
But how can i capture tab scroll!
now I add searchcontroll in each viewcontroller.

```
@interface CurrentToolListViewController : BaseViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
                UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *filterString;


@end
```

and .m file

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

self.searchController.delegate = self;

[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

self.tblCurToolList.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your searchController inactive in your **viewWillDisappear(_:)** method

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.searchController.active = NO;

}
```

**Edit**

The above code should fix your app from crashing if you *swipe* to the next ViewController, but if you are using a `UIButton` to call `setViewController`, then you have to check if the searchController is active (using an if statement) in the `UIButton`'s `@IBAction`. Inside the if statement, type `self.searchController.active = NO;`, and then `return`.

This just makes the searchController inactive, and then you have to press the button again to make it call the appropriate method (`setViewController`)